# When can I use 透?

Tags: word-choice

I came across these sentences

```
我浑身都湿透了。
这些芒果熟透了。
```

And MDBG lists these：

```
坏透，烂透，恨透，干透。
```

Should 透 only be used with these adjectives？

Comment: Here 透 is used as an adverb, "completely". But `这个人好透了` is wrong while `这个人坏透了` is OK, `我高兴透了` is wrong while `我烦透了` is OK ... I don't know why but it seems 透 is often used with some negative words.

Comment: Like @Stan said it's _often_ used with negative words, but not always. In your example, 熟透了 is neutral to positive. I think one difference between 透 and 完全/彻底 is formality. 透 is colloquial and rarely used in formal writing.

Comment: Is the meaning close to the "... to the core" expression? For instance, rotten to the core, soaked to the core.

Comment: @tao, yes, that or thoroughly.

Comment: @tao very good translation. "... to the core" keeps the image of `透` rather than just explaining its meaning.

Comment: 1、雨后，我走出家门，出来透透气。
2、一道阳光从乌云中透出来。
3、你这个人坏透了。

Comment: In your case, 透=彻底(thorough)=完全(completely), this is the meaning generally used. And 透 has the meaning as @Grower's answer as a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: When can I use 透?

Looking at the meanings:

`透` (tou4) = penetrate, pass through, transparent, to show

So, you can use it to applicable situations:

```
penetrate: 墨汁渗透了那张纸 (Mòzhī shèntòule nà zhāng zhǐ): The ink penetrated through the paper

pass through: 太阳射线穿透了窗口 (Tàiyáng shèxiàn chuān tòule chuāngkǒu): The sun rays passed through the window

transparent: 她穿的衬衫是透明的 (Tā chuān de chènshān shì tòumíng de): she wore a transparent top

to show/reveal: 他身上透出一股英气 (Tā shēnshang tòu chū yī gǔ yīngqì): he revealed his heroic spirit
```

The commonality here is that 透 means something that is revealing, or gets through something... So in any instance that occurs, you can probably use 透

Comment: "太阳射线 **穿透** 了窗口" sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my point

```
verb + 透: means "through", such as 穿 + 透，看 + 透
adj + 透: means "extreme", such as 湿 + 透, 糟 + 透
```

Comment: Welcome to Chinese SE. For answers, please try to elaborate as best as you can. If you believe this answer requires no further detail, please post it as a comment. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

As other explains,透 (tou4) = penetrate, pass through, transparent, to show,this is one meaning,the other is "completely"

Comment: If you agree with others' answers, please just upvote them :)

Comment: @Stan,I almost have not read any answer completely :)

Comment: @XL_at_China Reading some of the other answers is a good prerequisite for adding your own...

Comment: @StumpyJoePete,the time is not available sometimes